# safe type debounce function in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, debouncing

I have the following debounce function in typescript:

```
export function debounce<T>(
  callback: (...args: any[]) => void,
  wait: number,
  context?: T,
  immediate?: boolean
) {
  let timeout: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null;

  return (...args: any[]) => {
    const later = () => {
      timeout = null;

      if (!immediate) {
        callback.apply(context, args);
      }
    };
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    if (typeof timeout === "number") {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) {
      callback.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}
```

i'm looking for a better way to cast
`...args: any[]`
with a safer type.

How can i change it?

**UPDATE**

I came out with this solution:

```
export function debounce<T = unknown, R = void>(
  callback: (...args: unknown[]) => R,
  wait: number,
  context?: T,
  immediate?: boolean
) {
```

What do you think?

Comment: Add another generic parameter to this function: `debounce<T, F extends (...args: any[]) => any>`. Then the `callback` is of type `F` and `debounce` should return the same type `F`. This will allow the returned function to have the same type signature as the input function.

Comment: What type of `args` are you expect ?

Comment: i updated with the full function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made some changes.

First, we want the generic type to be a function so that later we can safely get the parameters with the `Paramters` utility type. Second, personally I like to have the wait time first because I frequently apply the same debounce timing to a lot of listeners with partial application, YMMV. Third, we want to return a regular (non-arrow) function with a typed `this` parameter so that the caller doesn't need to *explicitly* pass in a context.

```js
function debounce<T extends (...args: any[]) => void>(
  wait: number,
  callback: T,
  immediate = false,
)  {
  // This is a number in the browser and an object in Node.js,
  // so we'll use the ReturnType utility to cover both cases.
  let timeout: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null;

  return function <U>(this: U, ...args: Parameters<typeof callback>) {
    const context = this;
    const later = () => {
      timeout = null;

      if (!immediate) {
        callback.apply(context, args);
      }
    };
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    if (typeof timeout === "number") {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) {
      callback.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}
```

For usage we can use for both plain functions and methods:

```js
const handler: (evt: Event) => void = debounce(500, (evt: Event) => console.log(evt.target));
class Foo {
    constructor () {
        // can also type-safely decorate methods
        this.bar = debounce(500, this.bar.bind(this));
    }

    bar (evt: Event): void {
        console.log(evt.target);
    }
}
```

Even on the methods of object literals:

```js
interface Bar {
    a: number,
    f: () => void
}

const bar: Bar = {
    a: 1,
    f: debounce<(this: Bar) => void>(100, function() { console.log(this.a); }),
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=47&ssc=2&pln=44&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYCM7gqgPAFUVQA8pUxkBnRACgDoGBDAJwHNKAuRRsATwG0AugEpEAXgB8iAG5wYyCTQDujGFC5gQAW3SpmAGkQRGAGxPpGEANZd8hmFq2pkMRmXGJgpyqlGIA3gCwAFCIiCaoUIiwTljqiABKkSDMYPi8AA54UJmocMCIPlD4DnkgUFIAPoiaZgDcISFhzMmpntiwCIi4AKqKUAAWMJyIPYYMdCzsXAAKLIxOZMyUuDlZ+Uam5pZWEqJBoWFGCJRREAhkpB6Dww2HYedgp+Fueh40opIBTUdhMWVRMQ1ED1Rr3I4wAo0ACEDicLle+x+vweWws1kmGQyJl4NEelyghimlGEdxRiAAvsjKWSjo9nsYzAA5OBKDxw5yudwAMm5iGh-zid2pkNoazyBUF5XEYiBACJNDo9HKkeCHhEWCVYuUaFKoKTqVTgtS9R4ilqATQTK8DIgVGoDcbwaK8VsWUpVeTGdsMYwsTi8RcSITuGwSbSwkbI3cjSF6VEBjxkBFmFwaKhpPEAKLScj68RSWTyDxoTDYVA0ACsAAZq4Z05muDm858pPS4BE6CY4KwG1A6FAppFhI6INbKNQAGJwODfcHx5ggaBwZi0T3kxAAek3myQ3ln4oAtJRGMBUDiUKhzsxXohFgM4FRqb8bpQ6BZV0DS1hIBWa3XoiGN8P3fGAKF1ICRwjSkwV+D9aAzbNczAfUuCLZA5w3Y4ng7VAux7PsByHfVoKNWNgjApYvBwRAACEWEwo5GA0bRdAMalgDTVsZDkZAQnI+NEA-Lh6M-RiwmYxAAEZ9A4rhv3LXAIOGESWG49DFCk2tDFASBOjAD4AmwyhcPw3tX0mUlKWEWTgiNIA)

Answer (score 1):

I had fun thinking about all the edge cases here. In particular, making sure that the leading edge call (called `immediate` in your version) cannot occur back to back after itself, or after a trailing edge call. I used `unknown[]` to type `fn`'s arguments, which tells TypeScript to infer them (like `any`), and stick to the inferred types complaining if you attempt to switch to some new type which is incompatible with what was inferred in the first place (unlike `any`).

Rather than modifying your code, because of said edge cases, I chose to rewrite it from scratch, with a fair amount of
comments to convince myself that I didn't miss anything:

```js
interface DebounceOptions {
  // Whether the first call to the debounced function is run immediately.
  leading?: boolean;

  // Whether the last call to the debounced function is run after delay
  // milliseconds have elapsed since the last call.
  trailing?: boolean;
}

const defaultDebounceOptions: DebounceOptions = {
  leading: false,
  trailing: true
};

/**
 * Returns `fn` wrapped by a function that delays invoking `fn` for `delay` 
 * milliseconds since the last call. Set `options.leading` to invoke `fn` on
 * the leading edge of the delay, and/or set `options.trailing` to invoke `fn`
 * on the trailing edge of the delay (true by default).
 * 
 * Example for `debounce(fn, 30, {leading: true, trailing: true})`,
 * where `fn` is called twice, with the second call made 20 ms after the first:
 * 
 * Time:     0                   20                            50 (ms)
 * Timeline: |----------------------------------------------------------------|
 *           ^                   ^                             ^
 *           |                   |                             |
 *           | First call.       | Second call 20ms after the  | End of delay.
 *           | (instant leading  | first.                      | (trailing edge 
 *           |  edge call)       |                             |  call)
 *                               |-----------------------------|
 *                               |  30 ms delay for debounce.  |
 *
 * 
 * Note that if both `options.leading` and `options.trailing` are true, `fn`
 * will only be invoked on the trailing edge if the debounced function is called
 * more than once during the delay.
 *
 * @param fn - Function to debounce.
 * @param delay - Milliseconds to delay calling `fn` since the last call.
 * @param options - See `DebounceOptions` and `defaultDebounceOptions`.
 * @returns A debounced `fn`.
 */
export function debounce<T, A extends unknown[]>(
  fn: (this: T, ...args: A) => void, 
  delay: number,
  options: DebounceOptions = {}
): (this: T, ...args: A) => void {
  options = {...defaultDebounceOptions, ...options};
  
  let timer: number | undefined;

  return function(this: T, ...args: A): void {
    if (options.leading && !timer) {
      // Leading edge.
      // Call fn on the leading edge, when debouncing hasn't started yet.
      fn.apply(this, args);

      // Debounce the next call.
      timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
        timer = undefined;
      }, delay);
    } else {
      // Trailing edge.
      // Postpone calling fn until the delay has elapsed since the last call.
      // Each call clears any previously delayed call and resets the delay, so
      // the postponed call will always be the last one.
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
        if (options.trailing) {
          // Call fn on the trailing edge.
          fn.apply(this, args);

          if (options.leading) {
            // Debounce next leading call since a trailing call was just made.
            setTimeout(() => {
              timer = undefined;
            }, delay);
          }
        } else {
          // No trailing call. Since the delay has elapsed since the last call,
          // immediately reset the debouncing delay.
          timer = undefined;
        }
      }, delay);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt for a debounce function that does not use `any` and works with type inference.

```js
export function debounce<T extends (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>>(
  callback: T,
  wait: number,
  immediate?: boolean
): (...args: Parameters<T>) => void {
  let timeout: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;

  return function (this: ThisParameterType<T>, ...args: Parameters<T>): void {
    const later = () => {
      timeout = undefined;
      if (!immediate) callback.apply(this, args);
    };

    const callNow = immediate && timeout === undefined;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) callback.apply(this, args);
  };
}
```